# .net webapplication running on azure isn't in sync with data in sql

Tags: java, sql, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a Webapplication and database running on Azure. I have also made a java desktop application to add and delete rows in the db.
Now whenever i add or delete something in my database it will normally take half an hour to update the website. I want it to immediately update the website
[this is my site](http://climatecharttest.azurewebsites.net/)
I use Ms SQL server2013,java8,MVC5 and an azure student license
For example i add a new continent to the database:

```
    public class ContinentController : Controller
{
    private IGradeRepository repository;

    public ContinentController(IGradeRepository gradeRepository)
    {
        repository = gradeRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult ListContinents(int SelectedYear)
    {
       ViewBag.SchoolYear = SelectedYear;
       IEnumerable<Continent> continents = repository.FindBySchoolyear(SelectedYear).Continents;
       return View(continents.Select(co=>new ContinentsListViewModel(co)).ToList());
    }
```

this is my code in java

```
                repositoryController.insertContinent(new Continent(txtContinentName.getText().trim()));
            txtContinentName.clear();
```

I expect some kind of issue with azure, because when i tested it on my localdb everything worked.

Comment: You got to show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not an issue with Azure. If the changes from your Java code are actually committed to the database and not just in memory, then they will be visible immediately.

Without code we can only speculate, but I think you're not committing to the database from your Java code.

Comment: https://github.com/ArneDebremme/Hogent11Clone -> this our .NET repository
I'm committing to the right database from java 
proof; http://imgur.com/a/LZvmn climatecharttest_db is the linked resource of climatecharttest

Comment: The fact that you're connection string is correct, it doesn't necessarily mean that you're committing to the database. The ORM or Data access you're using might be writing to what looks to be the database, but as I said, those changes might just stay in memory until you commit them to the database. I don't have experience how this is done in Java, but this is the case in .NET and I'm sure it's exactly the same in Java as well.

Comment: For example, I've noticed you're using EclipseLink and after a bit of search, potential properties affecting the commit are: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_flush.htm#CBHFHGEB and http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_persistence_context_flushmode.htm#BABHDEJC. As I said, I'm no Java expert but there is absolutely no other reason why the database is not getting updated right away and only after XX amount of time.

Comment: Flushing the database didn't work unfortunately (or i did something wrong) however restarting the webapp on azure will update the data in the application.